# Power function in a loop

Tags: c++, loops

I need help with writing power function. So, I need to write a porogramm, that will output a table from 1 to 10 in a power in a LOOP. NOT USING POW or EXP
    Example of output:

```
0^0 == 1
1^1 == 1
2^2 == 4
3^3 == 27
4^4 == 256
(and so on, up to)
10^10 == 10000000000
```

NOT USING Cmath (NO POW or EXP)

for example:

e.g. power( 3.0, 5 ) will return 243 because 3*3*3*3*3 is 243
e.g. power( 173, 0 ) will return 1 because any number raised to the power of 0 is 1.

I did this Simple loop, But I have no idea how to insert power formula in it. I was also thinking about while loop

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std; 

int main(){

    int number = 0, tot;

    for (int table = 0; table < 10; table++)
    {
        tot = number * table;
        cout << tot << endl;
        number++;
    }    
}
```

Comment: You can [create your own function](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) and inside it, create the loop you need using one of [existing loop types in c++](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_loop_types.htm) (e.g: [for loop](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_for_loop.htm) ).

Comment: Create a loop that can multiply 3*3*3*3*3

Comment: @GermanMoiseenkov Great! Please edit your post with your solution, and what you are specifically stuck with and we'd be glad to help.

Comment: Side note: Your sample data are integers, only

Answer (score 0):

This is a recursive function that can calculate a value raised to an integer power

```
double power(double base, unsigned int exp)
{
    if (exp == 0)
    {
        return 1.0;
    }
    else
    {
        return base * power(base, exp - 1);
    }
}
```

An iterative method to do this would be

```
double power(double base, unsigned int exp)
{
    double product = 1.0;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < exp; ++i)
    {
        product *= base;
    }
    return product;
}
```

You can test either method with something like

```
int main()
{
    std::cout << power(5, 3);
}
```

Output

```
125
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you already know the answer to your own question by now, but still; some hints:

1. [Exponentiation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation) is a repeated multiplication of the base, the repetition is defined by the exponent.
2. In C++, or any modern programming language, loops allow repetition of certain blocks of code: when the number of iterations is known beforehand, use the for-loop, otherwise, use the while-loop.

Combining both hints: you'll need to use a loop to repeat a multiplication; the amount of repetition (or iterations) is known beforehand, thus, a for-loop will be best.

---

```cpp
int exponentiation(int base, int exponent) {
    int result = 1;
    for (int i = 0; i < exponent; ++i)
        result = result * base;
    return result;
}
```

**Note:** this will only suffice for integer exponentiation with positive exponents!

---

You can then call this function in a for-loop to let it compute the values you want:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    for(int i = 0; i <= 10; ++i)
        std::cout << exponentiation(i, i) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: I did that and it works fine, but it output last number which equal  1410065408, but 10^10 is suppose to be 10000000000. What is the problem in it?

Comment: That's because the integer type (`int`) is overflowing; in other words: 10^10 is too big to fit into the 32 bits that represent an integer. You'll need to replace all `int`s with `long` to be able to fit larger numbers inside them.

Comment: The `long int`, or `long`, is 64 bits on most modern machines; using it, you will be able to calculate up to 15^15 before overflowing again. [More info on **integer overflow** here.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow)